# In Xcode, what would make program work with breakpoint, but not without?

Tags: swift, xcode, breakpoints

I am using Swift. I have no way to explain this, but when I run my program normally, it crashes. From what I've gathered, it is having trouble with "let shuffled = (item as NSArray)...". I think it doesn't want to cast SKNode as an array of SKSpriteNodes.

But, when I put a breakpoint above "let shuffled =...", run it, then press "continue program execution" it works

how is this possible? what could be going wrong?

```
func createLevel() {
        
    var itemsToShow: Int = 5 + (level * 4)
    
    //create and shuffle an array of animals
    let animals = ["elephant.jpg", "giraffe.jpg", "hippo.jpg", "monkey.jpg", "panda.jpg", "parrot.jpg", "penguin.jpg", "pig.jpg", "rabbit.jpg", "snake.jpg"]
    
    var showAnimals = [String]()
    var placingAnimal = 0
    var numUsed = 0
    
    //find all nodes that belong to our scene that are not called "background"
    let items = children.filter { $0.name != "background" }
    //let items = children
    
BREAKPOINT HERE

    //shuffle those nodes so they are in a random order
    let shuffled = (items as NSArray).shuffled() as! [SKSpriteNode]

    //loop over these
    for item in shuffled {
        //hide eachone
        item.alpha = 0
    }
    
    var shuffledAnimals = (animals as NSArray).shuffled() as! [String] //this code is not what he wrote
    
    //remove one for the correct answer
    let correct = shuffledAnimals.removeLast()
    
    for _ in 1 ..< itemsToShow {
        //mark that we've used this animal
        numUsed += 1
        
        //place it in our array of strings "showAnimals"
        showAnimals.append(shuffledAnimals[placingAnimal]) //placingAnimals keeps track of the element in array 'shuffledAnimals'
        
        //if we've used this animal twice, go to the next one
        if numUsed == 2 {
            numUsed = 0
            placingAnimal += 1
        }
        
        // if w'eve gone through all animals, restart
        if placingAnimal == shuffledAnimals.count {
            placingAnimal = 0
        }
    } //for _ in 1 Loop
    
    for (index, animal) in showAnimals.enumerated() {
        //pull out matching item
        let item = shuffled[index]
        
        //assign correct texture
        item.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: animal)
        
        //show it
        item.alpha = 1
        //mark as wrong
        item.name = "wrong"
    }//for loop
    
    shuffled.last?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: correct)
    shuffled.last?.alpha = 1
    shuffled.last?.name = "correct"
    
}//createLevel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bridging to `NSArray` and force casting the type back is nonsense

```
let shuffledAnimals = animals.shuffled()
```

and

```
let shuffled = items.shuffled()
```